# ¿Como realizar un numero de combinaciones aleatorios en Java?

Tags: java

estoy intentando realizar un programa donde se pueda ingresar N cantidad de elementos en un Array y luego seleccionar 10 numeros aleatorios de los ya ingresados en ese array. Aquí está el código, pero me aroja una excepción.

```
package miaplicacion;
import java.util.*;
// @author eltec

public class MiAplicacion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random ran = new Random();

        System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros que ingresara");
        int cantidad = scan.nextInt();
        int[] numerosArray = new int[cantidad];

        int[] combinaciones = new int[10];

        for(int i=0; i<cantidad; i++){
            System.out.println((i+1)+"- Digite un numero");
            numerosArray[i] = scan.nextInt();            
        }//aqui ya se lleno el array

        for(int i= 0; i<numerosArray.length; i++){
            combinaciones[i] = numerosArray[ran.nextInt(10)];        
        }

        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
            System.out.println(combinaciones[i]);
        }       

    }  
}
```

El error que me muestra es este:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   10    at miaplicacion.MiAplicacion.main(MiAplicacion.java:23)
>   C:\Users\eltec\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el error que arroja? usa el boton [edit] y agrega como texto el error que te da, si no, no podemos ayudarte

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo hice.

Comment: Cual es la linea 10? seguro que es  combinaciones[i] = numerosArray[ran.nextInt(10)];

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Este seria el código, espero ayudarte.

```
package miaplicacion;
import java.util.*;
// @author eltec

public class MiAplicacion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random ran = new Random();

        System.out.println("Cantidad de numeros que ingresara");
        int cantidad = scan.nextInt();
        int[] numerosArray = new int[cantidad];

        int[] combinaciones = new int[10];

        for(int i=0; i<cantidad; i++){
            System.out.println((i+1)+"- Digite un numero");
            numerosArray[i] = scan.nextInt();            
        }//aqui ya se lleno el array

        System.out.println("Numeros Generados");
        for(int i= 0; i<=9; i++){
            combinaciones[i] = ran.nextInt(getMaxValue(numerosArray) - getMinValue(numerosArray) + 1) + getMinValue(numerosArray);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<=9; i++){
            System.out.println(combinaciones[i]);
        }       
    }

    // Obtiene el maximo valor del array
public static int getMaxValue(int[] array) {
    int maxValue = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = array[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}

// Obtiene el mínimo valor del array
public static int getMinValue(int[] array) {
    int minValue = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < minValue) {
            minValue = array[i];
        }
    }
    return minValue;
 }
}
```

Comment: y podrias explicar un poco porque este seria el codigo que soluciona el problema? mira [answer]

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i= 0; i<numerosArray.length; i++){
    combinaciones[i] = numerosArray[ran.nextInt(10)];        
}
```

Esa linea dentro del `for` es el problema, si bien el tamaño del array `combinaciones` esta fijado a `10`, el tamano del array `numerosArray` es dinamico y de acuerdo a lo que el usuario ingrese previamente.

Esto causa que si el numero aleatorio sea mayor al tamaño del arreglo, obtengas un `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

La solucion?, usa tu variable `cantidad`, la cual depende de lo que el usuario ingreso previamente, además esta variable se encarga de hacer el tamaño de tu array dinámico previamente:

```
for(int i= 0; i<numerosArray.length; i++){
    combinaciones[i] = numerosArray[ran.nextInt(cantidad)];        
}
```

De esta manera el rango de valores del entero siempre quedara entre `0` y el tamaño de tu array.

Se me olvido mencionar algo mas, estas usando el tamaño del array `numerosArray` para recorrerlo, esto funcionaria si no fuese porque el tamano de los arrays `numerosArray` y `combinaciones` puede no ser el mismo, debes asegurarte que en vez de usar un tamaño fijo en esta parte:

```
int[] combinaciones = new int[10];
```

Uses tu variable `cantidad` para definir su `tamaño`, ya que de esa manera los dos arreglos corresponderan con su `tamaño` de manera dinámica y podras recorrerlos con un `for` ya sea usando la referencia del tamaño de uno u otro.

Por lo tanto, debes cambiar esa linea a esta:

```
int[] combinaciones = new int[cantidad];
```

Y por si las moscas, seria bueno que como la asignación se la estas haciendo en el ciclo al array `combinaciones`, entonces en vez de hacer el ciclo tomando en cuenta el array `numerosArray`, hagas el ciclo tomando el cuenta el tamano del array `combinaciones`:

```
for(int i= 0; i< combinaciones.length; i++){
    combinaciones[i] = numerosArray[ran.nextInt(cantidad)];        
}
```

Comment: una cosa mas al respecto... si bien estas haciendo combinaciones aleatorias, con el codigo tal cual lo tienes, no necesariamente todos los espacios del array van a ser llenados, es mas!, algunos van a ser reemplazados por un valor que ya contenian, debido a que no te aseguras de que esa posicion en el array ya no haya sido llenada, considera esto, porque habra pocas ocasiones en las que la totalidad del array sea llenado con algun numero, los otros espacios quedaran vacios.

Comment: yo casi agregaria que seria un milagro si logra llenar el array aleatorio... y pensabamos lo mismo ;)

Comment: @Riven intenté lo que me dijiste pero aún el error continua. :(

Comment: Se me olvido comentarte algo, aquello que se me olvido comentar lo puse en la pregunta, (la edite), por favor revisala de nuevo a ver si ahora sirve ;3.

Comment: @Riven muchisimas gracias, tu solución me resultó de mucha ayuda. Un fuerte abrazo desde República Dominicana.

Comment: de nada amigo, tambien un saludo!, recuerda que si mi respuesta te fue de ayuda puedes darla como aceptada dandole click al boton que parece un chulo :3